# UIDatePicker Time Issues

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I have a problem with my UIDatePicker:

When it first appears on the view as you'll see in the screenshot,

the initial value of the UIDatePicker says Today 3:00 pm, but if I click on the done button the label shows 3:07 ( which is the actual time ).
I want the Label to display the same time as the UIDatePicker.

here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
   myDatePicker.minuteInterval = 15
}

@IBAction func datePickerAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"
    var strDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(myDatePicker.date)
    self.selectedDate.text = strDate
}
```

[image]
 [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to adjust the initial date to the discrete minute amounts at first. I am sure your date picker works just fine once you *change* the value, right? When you set the date picker to a date (like 3:07) but the date picker is set to show only increments of 15 minutes, it will show 3:00, but the set date is still 3:07.

```
let allUnits = NSCalendarUnit(rawValue: UInt.max)
let components = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(allUnits, fromDate: NSDate())

var minute = components.minute
minute = (minute / 15) * 15
components.minute = minute

let datePickerDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateFromComponents(components)
```

This always rounds the minutes downwards (while you might want to round up if the `minute % 15 > 7` and then account for rounding up to `60`), but you get the idea.